# How to remove this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'"

Tags: anaconda

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
 from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size =
 0.20, random_state = 0)
```

But its throwing this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
>
> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'**

Does anyone  know what could be the problem?

Comment: which version of sklearn you are using? if it is ```0.2``` or greater, then you can import ```train_test_split``` like this ```from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split```

Answer (score 0):

The error states:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'

Meaning your program dosent recognize this library, make sure you have installed it correctly following [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Format for input has changed from

`sklearn.cross_validation =>> sklearn.model_selection`